# No se manda a llamar metodo java, ayuda!

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hashmap

Hola buenos dias a todos, el dia de hoy estoy probando un método java y el problema es que no se manda a llamar, es un hashMap este es el codigo original que era "codigo duro" ya después se cambio de manera dinamica por medio de una consulta SQL dentro de un metodo, este es el original "duro":

```
{
        this.correspondencia=new HashMap<String, String>();
        correspondencia.put("A","101");
        correspondencia.put("B","102");
        correspondencia.put("B1","102");
        correspondencia.put("B2","102");
        correspondencia.put("B3","102");
        correspondencia.put("B4","102");
        correspondencia.put("BPR","102");
        correspondencia.put("C","102");
        correspondencia.put("DF","102");
        correspondencia.put("EFA","102");
        correspondencia.put("EXF","102");
        correspondencia.put("GPF","102");
        correspondencia.put("MB","102");
        correspondencia.put("MFA","102");
        correspondencia.put("P","102");
        correspondencia.put("PPR","102");
        correspondencia.put("PV","102");
        correspondencia.put("TF","102");
        correspondencia.put("UHN","102");
        correspondencia.put("B","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-1","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-2","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-3","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-4","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-5","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-6","103");
        correspondencia.put("DM","103");
        correspondencia.put("E","103");
        correspondencia.put("E1","103");
        correspondencia.put("E2","103");
        correspondencia.put("EC","103");
        correspondencia.put("EXM","103");
        correspondencia.put("IF","103");
        correspondencia.put("TM","103");
        correspondencia.put("TM1","103");
        correspondencia.put("DNC","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC1","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC2","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC3","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC4","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC5","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC6","104");
        correspondencia.put("NCC","104");
        correspondencia.put("TNC","104");
        correspondencia.put("TNC1","104");
        correspondencia.put("B","105");
        correspondencia.put("EX","105");
        correspondencia.put("F","107");
        correspondencia.put("GB","108");

    }


    private double calculaInversion(String nb_serie,List<VivVAACInversion> catalogoInversion) {
      //Aqui es donde se manda a llamar el map de arriba.`
        String clave=this.correspondencia.get(nb_serie);`
        double id=0;

        for (VivVAACInversion vivVAACInversion : catalogoInversion) {
            if(clave.equalsIgnoreCase(vivVAACInversion.getNombreClave())){
                id=vivVAACInversion.getIdInversion();
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Y este el codigo dinamico que quedó:

```
public static void correspondencia(){


        correspondencia=new HashMap<>();
        //Se reemplaza código duro por dinámico.
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            if(conn !=null) {
                String sql = "SELECT\r\n" + 
                        "    tviv055_intiserie.nb_serie,\r\n" + 
                        "    tviv053_inversion.nb_clave\r\n" + 
                        "FROM\r\n" + 
                        "    ( tviv056_relserie\r\n" + 
                        "    INNER JOIN tviv055_intiserie ON tviv056_relserie.cd_serie = tviv055_intiserie.cd_serie )\r\n" + 
                        "    INNER JOIN tviv053_inversion ON tviv056_relserie.cd_inversion = tviv053_inversion.cd_inversion";
                Statement stmt0 = conn.createStatement();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //Se llena el map con el resultado de la consulta.
                    correspondencia.put(rs.getString("NB_SERIE"), rs.getString("NB_CLAVE"));
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println( "SQL exception: " + e.getMessage());  
        }

    }

    private double calculaInversion(String nb_serie,List<VivVAACInversion> catalogoInversion) {
        String clave=this.correspondencia.get(nb_serie);
        double id=0;

        for (VivVAACInversion vivVAACInversion : catalogoInversion) {
            if(clave.equalsIgnoreCase(vivVAACInversion.getNombreClave())){
                id=vivVAACInversion.getIdInversion();
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Anexo esta imagen de unas advertencias que aparecen y me lanza un mensaje de "Dead code":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan brindar su ayuda, de antemano les mando un cordial saludo, y si falta por anexar que no esté entendido con gusto lo pondré.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes lo siguiente:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    if(conn !=null) {
    ...
```

Defines `conn` como `null` y luego dices *si no es null hago ...*.

Pero como `conn` **es** `null` ese código **nunca** se ejecutará.

Comment: Ya le cambié la validación a: if (conn == null) se salta al Statement y no se ejecuta, :(

Answer (score 0):

Antes del while te falta algo como esto:

```
rs = stmt0.executeQuery(sql);
```

Por eso indicaba que la variable sql estaba sin usar.

Saludos.

David

Comment: Si, se me pasó ese detalle jeje gracias por eso :)  y lo del "code dead" y que no se manda a llamar mi metodo correspondencia como lo podria mandar a llamar desde donde comenté? desde esta parte " //Aqui es donde se manda a llamar el map de arriba.`
        String clave=this.correspondencia.get(nb_serie);`"

Comment: Te falta un corchete

Comment: Ando revisando el codigo y no tienen corchetes. XD

Comment: Que te falta cerrar una llave }

Comment: Hola, no doy con esa llave jeje, podrias indicarme en que parte por favor amigo! saludos :)

Comment: Disculpa Juan José. Me pareció verlo en la imagen que colgaste.